# Mysql - estimate time to drop index

Tags: mysql, indexing

We have a fairly unoptimized table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `Usage` (
 `TxnDate` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TxnID` decimal(13,2) NOT NULL,
 `UserID2015` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `UserRMN` decimal(13,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `CustomerNo` decimal(13,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `OperatorName` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `AggregatorName` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `TransAmount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `MMPLTxnID` decimal(13,0) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ProductType` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `YearMonthRMN` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`TxnID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `TxnID` (`TxnID`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `TxnDate` (`TxnDate`),
 KEY `OperatorName` (`OperatorName`),
 KEY `AggregatorName` (`AggregatorName`),
 KEY `MMPLTxnID` (`MMPLTxnID`),
 KEY `ProductType` (`ProductType`),
 KEY `UserRMN` (`UserRMN`),
 KEY `YearMonthRMN` (`YearMonthRMN`) USING BTREE,
 KEY `CustomerNo` (`CustomerNo`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The table has abotu 170M records.

I want to drop the primary key and instead add an auto number primary key. So far the index dropping has taken 2h.

Why is it taking so long to remove an index, is there any sorting happening?

How can I estimate the time to drop the index?

When I add the autonumber, will I have to estimate time for sorting the table or will this not be necessary with a new autonumber index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not just dropping an index, you're dropping the primary key.

Normally, InnoDB tables are stored as a clustered index based on the primary key, so by dropping the primary key, it has to create a new table that uses either the secondary unique key or else an auto-generated key for its clustered index.

I've done a fair amount of MySQL consulting, and the question of "how much time will this take?" is a common question.

It takes as long as it takes to build a new clustered index on your server. This is hard to predict. It depends on several factors, like how fast your server's CPUs are, how fast your storage is, and how much other load is going on concurrently, competing for CPU and I/O bandwidth.

In other words, in my experience, it's not possible to predict how long it will take.

Your table will be rebuilt with `TxnID` as the new clustered index, which is coincidentally the same as the primary key. But apparently MySQL Server doesn't recognize this special case as one that can use the shortcut of doing an inplace alter.

Your table also has eight other secondary indexes, five of which are varchars. It has to build those indexes during the table restructure. That's a lot of I/O to build those indexes in addition to the clustered index. That's likely what's taking so much time.

You'll go through a similar process when you add your new auto-increment primary key. You could have saved some time if you had dropped your old primary key and created the new auto-increment primary key in one ALTER TABLE statement.

Comment: This is on Amazon RDS, so I could at least provision main memory for o log n space of the index sizes?

Comment: Index creation is usually constrained by I/O performance instead of memory.

Comment: Ok, but roughly I can calculate: I need x GB to sort the indexed columns in memory and I need x time to read through the columns, which is IO constrained? So I could temporarily assign the max IO available and enough memory, so sorting doesn't happen with swapping to disk

Comment: Index creation does not sort the data in memory or use swap. It creates the index incrementally on disk.

Comment: on another answer I read the index data needs sorting, which would happen in memory? Can I assume here it is sorted, as we are switching to the same field for the index?

Comment: You're probably thinking of sorted index builds, read more about them here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorted-index-builds.html This method of building indexes uses only a small amount of memory for the sort buffer. When the sort buffer gets full, the index build uses temporary disk files. The memory usage is much smaller than the total size of the index.

Answer (score 2):

(I agree with Bill's answer; here are more comments.)

I would kill the process and rethink whether there is *any* benefit in a `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

I try to look beyond the question to the "real" question.  In this case it seems to be something as-yet-unspoken that calls for an `AUTO_INCREMENT`; please elaborate.

Your current `PRIMARY KEY` is 6 bytes.  Your new PK will be 4 bytes if `INT` or 8 bytes if `BIGINT`.  So, there will be only a trivial savings or loss in disk space utilization.

Any lookups by `TxnID` will be slowed down because of going through the AI.  And since `TxnID` is `UNIQUE` and non-null, it seems like the optimal "natural" PK.

A PK *is a* Unique key, so `UNIQUE(TxnID)` is totally redundant; `DROPping` it would save space without losing anything.  That is the main recommendation I would have (just looking at the schema).

When I see a table with essentially every column being `NULL`, I am suspicious that the designer did not make a conscious decision about the nullness of the columns.

`DECIMAL(13,2)` would be a lot of dollars or Euros, but as a PK, it is quite unusual.  What's up?

`latin1`?  No plans for globalization?

Lots of single-column indexes?  `WHERE a=1 AND b=2` begs for a composite `INDEX(a,b)`.

Back to estimating time...

If the `ALTER` rebuilds the 8-9 indexes, then is *should* do what it can with a disk sort.  This involves writing stuff to disk, using an efficient disk-based sort that involves some RAM, then reading the sorted result to recreate the index.  A sort is O(log N), thereby making it non-linear.  This makes it hard to predict the time taken.  Some newer versions of MariaDB *attempt* estimate the remaining time, but I don't trust it.

A secondary index includes the column(s) being index, plus any other column(s) of the PK.  Each index in *that* table will occupy about 5-10GB of disk space.  This *may* help you convert to IOPs or whatever.  But note that (assuming you don't have much RAM), that 5-10GB will be reread a few (several?) times during the sort that rebuilds the index.

When doing multiple `ALTERs`, do them in a single `ALTER` statement.  That way, all the work (especially rebuilding of secondary indexes) need be done only once.

You have not said what version you are using.  Older versions hand one choice:  "COPY":  Create new table; copy data over; rebuild indexes; rename.  New versions can deal with *secondary* indexes "INPLACE".  Note:  changes to the `PRIMARY KEY` require the copy method.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. This is a database with transactions out of India, hence the size of decimal. The data import process is substandard, hence the operator can't trust TxnId and needs the auto number to identify the import works. I'm pushing for having this database retired as we have a newer, better set up one, but we're not there yet. On top of this, I appreciate the calculations provided, as this will help optimise the newer database. MySQL is 5.7

Comment: Even with more info, any computation would be only approximate -- many things cause BTrees to grow/shrink.  Still, I think 5-10GB is about right.  `latin1` means that none of the many Indian languages can be stored 'correctly'.  utf8mb4 (or utf8) should be used for the new setup.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested:

- This is run on Amazon Aurora with 30GB of data stored. I could not find any information on how IOPS is provisioned for this, but I expected at worst case there would be 90IOPS available consistently. To write 10GB in and out would take around 4 hours.
- I upgraded the instance to db.r3.8xlarge before running the alter table.
- Then ran

  ```
  alter table `Usage` drop primary key, add id bigint auto_increment primary key
  ```

it took 1h 21m, which is much better than expected.